# React - How to pass data from html to React constructor

Tags: html, reactjs

I am learning react and playing around it. My existing project is using java from the backend and planning to integrate React at the frontend. I am having challenge, when the page got loaded first time, java will return a jsp with list of items. I need to pass this list of items into React constructor for state initialize.

How to pass the list to React constructor?

Thanks!!!

The following are my program:-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ItemList extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         itemList: this.props.items;
      };
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <table id="item-table" className="table table-hover">
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.itemList.map((item, i) => <TableRow key = {i} item = {item} />)}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      );
   }
};

class TableRow extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <tr>
            <td>{this.props.item.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.item.no}</td>
            <td>{this.props.item.amount}</td>
         </tr>
      );
   }
}

export default ItemList;

ReactDOM.render(<ItemList/>, document.getElementById('item-list'));
```

Comment: First you need to create a JS object which will contains the items from the jsp, then you need to pass it as props of the ItemList component : `ReactDOM.render(<ItemList items={yourItemsJsObject}/>, document.getElementById('item-list'));`

Comment: thanks for your replied. but how can i set the list into the ReactDOM.render? ReactDOM.render is located in the jsx file.

Comment: you need to store the JS object as global variable in your jsp, then you can access it in the ReactDOM.render function. I think it's a bad idea to transmit js object from your jsp to react, it will be better to call an ajax service directly in the componentWillMount method to retrieve the list of items

Comment: better to do it in **componentDidMount** to avoid some issues

Comment: if I do it in componentDidMount mean i have to return an empty page without the list and use ajax call to get the list from the server again? mean it will hit the server 2 times for the list to display.

Comment: in that case you don't have to load the item list the first time, you only need it for the ajax request

Comment: Yes, first time get the empty page, without the list. second time use ajax call to get the list and display. This required to hit the server 2 times to display the list. This is best practice?

Comment: yes unless you want to use server side rendering but it add some complexity. in my opinion using an ajax call is the best solution for your case

Comment: @stanicmail, Olivier is on the right track with his assistance, I would follow his lead and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping things true to the way you have it now

- Insert the list into a javascript file on the page and make it accessible
- Inside a `componentDidMount` update the state with something like

  ```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ myList: global.MYCOMPANY.myList });
  }
  ```

You can also move your fetch to something inside your component. This is where you can start to leverage other pieces of react ecosystems like redux/thunk or just DIY....

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/getList')
            .then((rs) => {
                this.setState({ myList: rs });
            })
    }
```

I used arrow functions for brevity. The `render` method in your class will get called every time your state changes. You can choose to return nothing, empty lists or even a loading icon here if need be. This is still fairly entry level of a solution or works for tiny projects, but is a good place to start before looking to scale outwards.